# How to exclude a column/ field ('ID') from the showing amongst value counts using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to list the value count per each 'object' and 'int64' column/ field. However, customer ID 'ID' is an int64 column. I'd like to exclude this from my output. What is the simplest and most efficient way to do so?

Below is my current/ written script followed by its output.

```
for c in df.select_dtypes('object' and 'int64').columns:
        print(f"{c}: \n\n{df[c].value_counts()}\n")
```

[image]

Do let me know if you need clarification as to my objective or additional comments.

Comment: If possible, I'd like it to list both the counts of the 'object' and 'int64' columns. I realized that the use of an 'and' did not achieve the desired output. Any advice/ guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: `for c in df.drop("ID", axis=1).select_dtypes('object' and 'int64').columns`?

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking me a question?

Comment: I'm asking if trying that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
for c in df.select_dtypes(['object','int64']).columns:
    if c != 'ID':
        print(f"{c}: \n\n{df[c].value_counts()}\n")
```